# String animation in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

How do I change the Content property of say a Button? Maybe with StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  [StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stringanimationusingkeyframes.aspx) is specifically designed for animation of strings.  It should be usable for a button's content.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use styles and triggers.